# Why, when sending BTC to my pruned node's generated wallet, the BTC aren't showing there?

Tags: bitcoind, server, bitcoin-cli

:) I'm starting development on a PHP project that involves creating a Bitcoin server, creating and managing wallets, etc.

I've created a selfish-node (550 MiB of the blockchain) on Ubuntu 14 with bitcoind and bitcoin-cli and it is live according to https://bitnodes.21.co/ => response: (162.243.145.144:8333 /Satoshi:0.14.2/)

My bitcoin.conf is as follows

`prune=550
maxconnections=10
maxuploadtarget=10
rpcuser=fakeusername
rpcpassword=fakepassword
daemon=1
keypool=10000`

and bitcoin-cli getinfo outputs

`root@b:~/.bitcoin# bitcoin-cli getinfo
{
  "version": 140200,
  "protocolversion": 70015,
  "walletversion": 130000,
  "balance": 0.00000000,
  "blocks": 367670,
  "timeoffset": -1,
  "connections": 8,
  "proxy": "",
  "difficulty": 52278304845.59168,
  "testnet": false,
  "keypoololdest": 1505160918,
  "keypoolsize": 10000,
  "paytxfee": 0.00000000,
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "errors": ""
}`

I've created a wallet via bitcoin-cli on this node: 17Jn1VYpwknwjuVxLMYvqc8iHJ6QsP8xDo and have sent this address 0.00000547 bitcoin as a test from an Electrum wallet of mine.

The tx: ee65b8201e0e26827430b34872f6dd961f318e0c1e4c5266a6bcf8a8fa22a2ce

According to the blockchain, it has over 10 confirmations at this point (it is confirmed).

But when I execute commands to verify this from within my server, it does not show any such transaction and it does not show that I have received any funds.

`root@b:~/.bitcoin# bitcoin-cli getreceivedbyaddress 17Jn1VYpwknwjuVxLMYvqc8iHJ6QsP8xDo`

Outputs

`0.00000000`

and

`root@b:~/.bitcoin# bitcoin-cli gettransaction ee65b8201e0e26827430b34872f6dd961f318e0c1e4c5266a6bcf8a8fa22a2ce`

Outputs

`error code: -5
error message:
Invalid or non-wallet transaction id`

Is this because I am not running a full node? Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Did you wait for your transaction to be accepted in the next bitcoin block? I can see your transaction here https://blockchain.info/tx/ee65b8201e0e26827430b34872f6dd961f318e0c1e4c5266a6bcf8a8fa22a2ce

Comment: I did wait. It was confirmed. The problem, I believe, is that this transaction is not synced with the node on my server yet, since the node is new (I just installed it a few hours before). I have to wait until my node syncs then I will check it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your node isn't synced with the blockchain yet.

```
 "blocks": 367670,
```

Your node has downloaded and verified 367670 blocks.  According to https://blockchain.info/ there are currently 484790 blocks in the blockchain.  Your node will not have an up-to-date view of the transaction register until it has downloaded and processed all of them.  At that time, your transaction should become visible to your node.

Comment: Is there a way to speed up the syncing of my node through my bitcoin.conf file?

Comment: @luminol: In my experience it tends to be CPU bound.  Check `top` to see your CPU usage; if it's already 100% then there is not really anything that will improve it.  If not then you could try increasing `maxconnections` and `maxuploadtarget` in hopes of downloading faster (the latter might be limiting how quickly you can request blocks).